# Calling multiple documents from nested collection firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a nested collection in firebase that goes like this:

```
await fire.firestore()
    .collection("groupsCategory")
    .doc(groupID)
    .collection('events')
    .doc(eventID)
    .collection("memberPicks")
    .onSnapshot((querySnapshot) => {
        if(isMounted){
            console.log("print indi event heree  " + querySnapshot.data().eventID)
       
            setEventName(querySnapshot.data().eventName)
            // setIndividualEventDetails(querySnapshot.data())
        }
```

when we get to memberPicks collection it looks like this:
[image]

What I'm trying to do is basically add all of the contents of this collection to a list so that I can count how many times each name is called.

But I am failing to combine all of the documents in this collection with the code I have above and I am not sure where I am going wrong

Comment: The Firebase Realtime Database and Cloud Firestore are two separate databases. I fixed it here already, but going forward please only mark your question with the relevant tag, not with both.

Answer (score 0):

Your `querySnapshot` is a [`QuerySnapshot` object](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot), which represents a list of documents. So it doesn't have any `data()` property itself, but instead exposes a list of documents in its `docs` property.

To show the event ID for each of the documents in your query snapshot, you could do:

```
.onSnapshot((querySnapshot) => {
    if(isMounted){
        querySnapshot.docs.forEach((doc) => {
            console.log(doc.data().eventID)
   
            setEventName(doc.data().eventName)
        });
    }
```

Comment: hi will this get all of the data thats inside the memberPicks collection?

Comment: I didn't change anything about that code, but yeah... `.collection("memberPicks")` gets all documents in that subcollection of the given `eventID`.

Comment: Hi Frank, when I do the code there and i push it to a list hook, it only gives me an array of one users document and I'm not sure why

Comment: I'm not sure what "it" means in there, but the `console.log` should log the event ID of every document in the `memberPicks` subcollection of the given `eventID`. Is that not happening for you? Or are you referring to problems further down the line?